# How to create dynamic routes with dynamic pattern in iron-router package of Meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am using Meteor to create a sample website. I am using `iron-router` for routing. I want to have folder style navigation. Lets say, if the url is "xyz.com/f/2/4/5/d/7", then 2 is the root folder, 4 is sub-folder of 2, 5 is sub-folder of 4 and 7 is the document inside the folder 5. But the problem is the number of parameters between f and d, in the url, are dynamic, which means that another URL can be "xyz.com/f/2/4/d/6", where there are only 2 folders. How to define routes in such a scenario?

The actual routes doesn't represent real folders and files but I have mentioned it in that way to make things simple.

Comment: Use wildcard? Like `path: '/something/*'`.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. What if you have a sub-folder called f or d?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. We have avoided this scenario completely.